# How to add the occurrences of a value in a SQL table specific to another value in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched and think I have found part of my answer, but I still can't quite figure it out. I have a database with 4 tables and I'm trying to return for each employee their name, the number of total vacation days they have which is based on their job title and the number of vacation days they have taken wich is found by adding up all of instances where the ReasonID column of the Leave table equals 2 for that employee.

This is what I have, and if I take out the line where I'm trying to get VacationDaysTaken, I can return the correct EmployeeName and TotalVactionDays. If I just try to return VacationDaysTaken, then I get the number of vacation days used by all employees. If I try to run it as I have it listed below, I get "Column 'Employee.Last' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

```
SELECT
Employee.Last + ', ' + Employee.First AS EmployeeName,
Title.Vacation AS TotalVacationDays,
SUM(CASE WHEN Leave.ReasonID=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VacationDaysTaken
FROM Employee, Title, Leave, LeaveType
WHERE Employee.EmpID = Leave.EmpID 
    AND Leave.ReasonID = LeaveType.ReasonID 
    AND Employee.TitleID = Title.TitleID
ORDER BY EmployeeName
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

You need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT e.Last + ', ' + e.First AS EmployeeName,
       t.Vacation AS TotalVacationDays,
        SUM(CASE WHEN l.ReasonID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VacationDaysTaken
FROM Employee e JOIN
     Title t
     ON e.TitleID = t.TitleID JOIN
     Leave l
     ON e.EmpID = l.EmpID
GROUP BY e.Last, e.First, t.Vacation
ORDER BY EmployeeName;
```

Note:  Because you are using the `ReasonId` for the comparison, there is no need to join to the leave types table.